# Terminal redirection to file Result into trash code

Tags: c, bash

I'm a student, now try to program a tool  to process  text files writen In Chinese(replace part of the text).My operating system is ubuntu 14.04, with bash terminal.I am using 'getchar' and 'putchar' To manipulate the text flow.

However, when my small tool print the result on the terminal screen, everything is okay, the terminal prints good chinese words , but when I try to use ">" to redirect the output to a file, the file is just trash code. How can I fix this ?

The following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main ()

{
int n,i,label;
char c;
for (n = 0, label = 0; (c =getchar ()) !=EOF&& (label== 0);) {
    if ( c=='\n'){
        n++ ;
        putchar ('\n');
        if ( n==2 ) {
            label = 1;
            printf ("<d p=\"10.27899169922,1,25,65280,1423545124,0,4dc93e5c,722222222\">I 'm the maker ..........</d>\n");
        }
    }
    else
        putchar (c);
}
label = 0;
for (; (c=getchar())! =EOF;)
    putchar (c);
putchar (c);
}
```

Comment: What encoding does your source code have? How about your terminal? Have you tried different encodings for opening the file created by the '>' pipe? (Chances are it's either UTF-8 or GB2312.)

Comment: First of all, [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) doesn't return a `char`, it returns an `int` (which is very important). Secondly, if you read e.g. [UTF-8 encoded text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (like Chinese most likely will be) then you have to remember that it's a variable-length encoding.